# Add loose edges between mutiple edges of different lengths

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm having a scenario like below. I have one long edge and 3 smaller edges like shown below[image]

I want to add edges between the corresponding edges like this. Below is a picture of what I want when done manually
[image]

But when I use bridge edge loops, I'm getting something like this:
[image]

My doubt is, is there a way in which I can draw the required edges using a script and not manually?

Comment: Bridge Edge Loops will fill that but if empty spaces between those small islands are filled with edges. Do you need edges to converge exactly where the empty space is ([located here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIKys.png))? Bridge won't be able to get them like that of course.

Comment: I can't fill the empty spaces with edges because I want to keep them separated. So my application is actually adding springs for different cloth patterns. Say if 3 small pieces of cloth are getting stitched to a bigger cloth piece, and I dont want to add these springs manually.